# Including content of php file in html page

Tags: php, html, facebook

My php file is:

```
<?php
session_start();

    if (!class_exists('FacebookApiException')) {
    require_once('facebook.php' );
    }
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $appId,
        'secret' => $appSecret,
    ));
    $fbuser = $facebook->getUser();
 if ($fbuser) {
        try {
         $user_interest = $facebook->api('/me/movies');
        echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($user_interest);
        }
 catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
  }}
?>
```

I want to use $user_interest and other var in html code in php file:
I tried in following way which gives error $user_interest not defined.

```
<?php
session_start();
$appId = '619'; 
$appSecret = 'myverybeatuifuldaisygiveusmilk'; // Facebook App Secret
$return_url = 'http://yoursite.com/connect_script/';  //path to script folder
$fbPermissions = 'publish_stream,email'; //more permissions : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/
require_once('facebook.php' );
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $appId,
        'secret' => $appSecret,
    ));
    $fbuser = $facebook->getUser();
     $user_interest = $facebook->api('/me/movies');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" ><head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>JS/Ajax Facebook Connect</title>
 <script>
 function AjaxResponse()
 {
    var myData = 'connect=1'; 
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process_facebook.php",
    data: myData
    }).done(function(result) {
    $("#fb-root").html(result);
    });
   }


 </script></head><body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId: '<?php echo $appId; ?>',
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
//  channelUrl: '<?php echo $return_url; ?>channel.php',
    oauth: true});};
document.write($user_interest);
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);}());

function CallAfterLogin(){
        FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.status === "connected")
        {
            LodingAnimate(); //Animate login
            FB.api('/me', function(data) {
            console.log($user_interest);

              }); 
         }     });  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ugly and dirty code is the reason why i'm wanderring on this website instead of working. It's annoying and takes time to read, fix and improve. Think about people who will read you. Ffs.

Comment: ohhh you posted your app secrete key and app id ... you have done a wrong thing ... :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the line

```
console.log($user_interest);
```

to:

```
console.log('<?php echo $user_interest; ?>');
```

Comment: thanks buddy. But for above code it gives this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 28: Operation timed out after 10017 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/FB/facebook-php-sdk/examples/base_facebook.php on line 994` process_facebook.php has line `require_once "base_facebook.php";`

Answer (score 2):

You are using the variable $user_interest outside of the php context. 
It should be placed in php-Tags like so:

```
<?php echo $user_interest; ?>
```

Comment: thanks buddy. But for above code it gives this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 28: Operation timed out after 10017 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/FB/facebook-php-sdk/examples/base_facebook.php on line 994` process_facebook.php has line `require_once "base_facebook.php";`